# One-click access to alarm settings

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, alarm, clock

I want to access the alarm clock feature built into Jelly Bean in one click. In the past, I've always done this by tapping the analog clock that's on the home screen by default. I want to switch to a third-party clock widget now, and it doesn't leave me enough room to keep the analog clock on the screen. (Besides, having two clocks would look weird.)

The only other way to get to the alarm clock setup page, as far as I know, is to open the clock widget and then tap on the "next alarm" bar. That, of course, takes a minimum of two clicks. How can I do it in one?

Answer (score 3):

Some launchers (Nova, Launcherpro) can create shortcut on home screen which can launch custom activity from any app. This may allow you to launch alarm settings directly.

Also you can create custom app to launch activity from another app.