# Is there a nice one click alarm for android?

Tags: alarm

Sometimes when I'm tired, I take a nap of 1 hour. Doing that with the native clock on Android requires a lot of clicks. I would like to have an app that whenever the button is pressed, it starts to count 1 hour.

Comment: [Setting alarm on with a single click](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43385) and [One-click access to alarm settings](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30441)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you want is a timer rather than an alarm clock. (Did you look in the Play Store?)

One very simple timer app I use is [Tick!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rabugentom.tick).

1. Tap to open
2. Use your finger to spin the dial to the amount of time you want to count down
3. Tap to start the timer

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Now:

say "OK Google Now",

say "Set Alarm for one hour",

then touch "Set Alarm"

Answer (score 0):

You could try an app called Simple Alarm Clock by a developer called Moula soft Inc.  It is in the google app store. I like it.